# Aggregating across a multiple choice question data structure

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that has a multiple choice question that's been broken out so each option is its own column. I also have weight column and I'm looking to aggregate across each column of the multiple choice to find the sum of the weight column that selected that option. I know I could do this in a for loop to go across each column, but I was looking for a cleaner method.

Any suggestions?

Dput:

```
structure(list(`Medical (treatment for any diagnosed medical condition)` = c("0", 
NA, "0", "Medical (treatment for any diagnosed medical condition)", 
"Medical (treatment for any diagnosed medical condition)", "Medical (treatment for any diagnosed medical condition)", 
"Medical (treatment for any diagnosed medical condition)", "0", 
"0", "0"), `Dental (preventive or routine care for oral health)` = c("0", 
NA, "0", "Dental (preventive or routine care for oral health)", 
"0", "Dental (preventive or routine care for oral health)", "Dental (preventive or routine care for oral health)", 
"0", "0", "0"), `Vision (preventive or routine care for eye health)` = c("0", 
NA, "Vision (preventive or routine care for eye health)", "Vision (preventive or routine care for eye health)", 
"0", "Vision (preventive or routine care for eye health)", "0", 
"0", "0", "0"), `Wellness incentives program (such as smoking cessation or weight loss programs)` = c("0", 
NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Wellness incentives program (such as smoking cessation or weight loss programs)", 
"Wellness incentives program (such as smoking cessation or weight loss programs)"
), `Gym membership` = c("0", NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Gym membership", 
"Gym membership", "Gym membership"), `Life insurance` = c("Life insurance", 
NA, "Life insurance", "Life insurance", "0", "Life insurance", 
"0", "0", "0", "Life insurance"), `Accidental death and dismemberment` = c("0", 
NA, "0", "Accidental death and dismemberment", "0", "Accidental death and dismemberment", 
"0", "0", "0", "0"), `Health savings account (HSA)` = c("0", 
NA, "0", "0", "Health savings account (HSA)", "Health savings account (HSA)", 
"Health savings account (HSA)", "0", "0", "Health savings account (HSA)"
), `Flexible spending account (FSA)` = c("0", NA, "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), `Health reimbursement arrangements (HRA)` = c("Health reimbursement arrangements (HRA)", 
NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", "Health reimbursement arrangements (HRA)", 
"0", "0", "0"), `State medical savings program (MSP)` = c("0", 
NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "State medical savings program (MSP)", 
"0", "0"), `Pharmacy card` = c("0", NA, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0"), `Over-the-counter/supplemental benefits` = c("0", 
NA, "0", "0", "Over-the-counter/supplemental benefits", "Over-the-counter/supplemental benefits", 
"0", "0", "0", "0"), `Other, please specify:` = c("0", NA, "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), weight = c(102099.073110486, 
99927.5001779742, 100569.577453382, 98542.6996469168, 38237.391427588, 
82498.4815047276, 99924.9006748349, 82498.4815047276, 79954.3106465319, 
91795.9294203397)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(setdiff(names(df1), "weight"),
   ~  df1 %>% 
       select(.x, weight) %>%
       group_by(across(all_of(.x))) %>%
       summarise(weight = sum(weight, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! What does the .x do in these snippets?

Comment: This does everything I need, but the output is as a list. Would it be possible to transform this to a dataframe that stacks all the aggregate outputs on top of each other to end up with a column containing all sum weights and a column denoting which multiple choice option the weights belonged to?

Comment: I was able to fix this with adding %>% data.table::rbindlist(., use.names = FALSE) to the end

Comment: @ZArmstrong you can use `map_dfr` instead of `map` if you want to rbind

Answer (score 0):

We could `pivot_longer()` and then `count(name, value, wt = weight)`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = - weight) %>% 
  count(name, value, wt = weight)

#> # A tibble: 39 × 3
#>    name                                                value                   n
#>    <chr>                                               <chr>               <dbl>
#>  1 Accidental death and dismemberment                  0                  5.95e5
#>  2 Accidental death and dismemberment                  Accidental death … 1.81e5
#>  3 Accidental death and dismemberment                  <NA>               9.99e4
#>  4 Dental (preventive or routine care for oral health) 0                  4.95e5
#>  5 Dental (preventive or routine care for oral health) Dental (preventiv… 2.81e5
#>  6 Dental (preventive or routine care for oral health) <NA>               9.99e4
#>  7 Flexible spending account (FSA)                     0                  7.76e5
#>  8 Flexible spending account (FSA)                     <NA>               9.99e4
#>  9 Gym membership                                      0                  5.22e5
#> 10 Gym membership                                      Gym membership     2.54e5
#> # … with 29 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>